# EF Core executing previously failed query on SaveChanges

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We have a `.Net Core 3.1` application which is using `EF Core` to connect wit the `SQL Server` database. We are facing one problem, that when an `exception` occurs in our method due to some reason, for example, a field is mandatory in DB and on `SaveChanges`, `Exception` is raised, because the value for that field was passed as null, then next time, when the same method is called with different parameters (even with all correct/mandatory fields), still the old query gets executed in `EF Core` (I checked this in `Output` window). Which is very weird and strange behavior.

If we close the application (in debug environment) after the first exception and re run the application with correct payload next time, then everything works fine. May be the `EF Core` is retrying the earlier failed query again for some reason? or why is this behavior occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how are you getting messages from the queue, the message may come back to the queue if it is not acknowledge after a while.

With Auto Acknowledge the message will is removed permanently. If you ack after persist in the database, any exception will avoid the ack, so the message goes back to the queue.

Comment: its not an issue with queue/RMQ I believe. for some weird reason, EF is executing the previously failed query (checked in output window).

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that the RabbitMQ consumer classes were not properly setup in the Dependency Configuration file. Basically the repository cases were instantiated as static members in the Dependency Config and when Consumers were setup for RabbitMQ, they were passed in these static Repository objects. I removed these static objects, and made use of the Scoped instances of the repository. this resolved my issue.